# Count distinct values for day in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I have a table that has the next values:

```
sta_datetime | calling_number |called_number
01/08/2019    |   999999          | 9345435
01/08/2019    |   999999         | 5657657
02/08/2019    |   999999         | 5657657
03/08/2019    |   999999         | 9844566
```

I want a query that counts the uniques values for each date in all the month , for example:

```
sta_datetime | calling_number  | quantity_calls
01/08/2019   |   999999        |   2
02/08/2019   |  999999         |  0
03/08/2019   |  999999         |  1
```

In date 02/08/2019 is 0 because the called_numbers are repited in date 01/08/2019.

Comment: What if there is a gap of more than one day for the called number?

Comment: how is called number  counted on 1 st date only moreover if there are multlple calling numbers  which date it should be added to????

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have records on each day, you can just count the first in a series of days with a given called number by using `lag()`:

```
select sta_datetime, calling_number,
       sum(case when prev_sta_datetime = sta_datetime - 1 then 0 else 1 end) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             lag(sta_datetime) over (partition by calling_number, called_number order by sta_datetime) as prev_sta_datetime
      from t
     ) t
group by sta_datetime, calling_number
order by sta_datetime, calling_number;
```

If you only want to count the first date `called_number` was called, then:

```
select sta_datetime, calling_number,
       sum(case when first_sta_datetime = sta_datetime then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             min(sta_datetime) over (partition by calling_number, called_number) as first_sta_datetime
      from t
     ) t
group by sta_datetime, calling_number
order by sta_datetime, calling_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `not exists` and then `group by` as following:

```
Select t1.sta_datetime, t1.calling_number, count(1) as quantity_calls
from your_table t1
Where not exists 
   (select 1 from 
    your_table t2
    Where t2.sta_datetime < t1.sta_datetime
    and t1.calling_number = t2.calling_number
    and t1.called_number = t2.called_number
    and trunc(t1.sta_datetime, 'month') = trunc(t2.sta_datetime, 'month'))
Group by t1.sta_datetime, t1.calling_number
Order by t1.calling_number, t1.sta_datetime;
```

Cheers!!